# regex negation in a pattern

Tags: regex, checkstyle, regex-negation

I'm trying to define a regex pattern with a negation within the pattern. I want to exclude all strings with 'Test' on the end. I'm aware about the character negation `[^Test]` but this is not what I'm looking for, `[^Test]` is equal to `[^estT]`. It should pass for strings like `UserService` and not for `UserServiceTest`. So what I did is to exclude that with `{min,max}`. but it doesn't work :(.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(Test){0,0})$
```

My origin idea is to put this pattern into checkstyle suppress configuration, and exclude all the Test classes from checkstyle check.

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
  <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
  <module name="TypeName">
    <property name="format" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]+(Test){0,0})"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

Do anyone know how can I fix this issue?

Cheers,

Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?<!Test))$
```

Note that not all regular expression engines support lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^(Test)]
```